# On meaning of conservation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, conservation-laws, hamiltonian-formalism

Consider a (for now classical) system with a Hamiltonian $H(\vec{q},\vec{p})$. The system starts from a point in the phase space ($2N$ dimensional) and travels along a $trajectory$. Let $\Pi$ and $T$ denote the phase space and the set of all possible trajectories allowed by the Hamiltonian respectively. There are some conserved quantities like Hamiltonian itself and others which satisfy
$$\frac{dQ}{dt}=\{H,Q\}=0$$ 
We want to somehow $count$ the number of conserved quantities.

a) Given a number of conserved functions develop a definition of $independent$ ones. For example $H$, $H^2$, $e^{-\beta H}$ are all conserved but we don't want to count them as 3 conserved quantities.

b) are there always $2N-1$ $independent$ conserved (possibly not continuous) quantities that determine the path uniquely? note that I am essentially asking if you can somehow assign a number to paths in the phase space in a one to one and onto manner ($T\leftrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2N-1}$)

It is easy to show that sometimes there are no $2N-1$ continuous conserved quantities. For example take the system of two decoupled harmonic oscillators with irrational ratio of frequencies
$$H=\frac{1}{2}(p_1^2+p_2^2)+\frac{1}{2}q_1^2+q_2^2$$
The trajectory $fills$ a 2 dimensional entity and hence is not a cross section of three different surfaces of constant conserved quantities.

c) Let $\Delta$ denote the dimension of a $general$ path in the phase space (This dimension can be simply defined. Use the intuition for now) Is there a method for finding $\Delta$ given the Hamiltonian? (Note that $2N-\Delta$ is the number of conserved quantities)

Remark: If all the trajectories are periodic, $\Delta=1$. Hydrogen atom and isotropic $n$-dimensional harmonic oscillator are examples.

d) Is there a dynamical system 
$$\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}=\vec{v}(\vec{x})$$
that has no continuous conserved quantities? (The pathlines should fill the whole space!)

We know that conserved quantities are the quantum numbers in the quantum mechanical corresponding problem. And we note that there are extra quantum numbers (due to degeneracy) in both isotropic SHO ($n_x, n_y, n_z$) and Hydrogen atom ($n, l, m$).

e) Prove or disprove "The number of quantum numbers to specify non-degenerate eigenstates of Hamiltonian is the number of classical conserved quantities minus $N-1$"